# Unable to add Rows and Columns in Grid

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

i recently came through this [Codepen article](https://codepen.io/semblance/pen/XexVbB). I love this layout and but there is some confusion here.
I am not able to add more rows and columns in the layout.
When i try to add more figure and article it overlaps with the last 4th one.
here is the link

Trying to add this blog post to article makes it overlap

```
 <figure class="featured-image-3 ">
            <img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/579121/seth-doyle-151915-sm.jpg" alt="Photo by Seth Doyle on Unsplash">
        </figure>
        <div class="number-3">5</div>
        <article class="article article-3">
            <h2>Introduction of the Study</h2>
            <p>The toppings you may chose for that TV dinner pizza slice when you forgot to shop for foods, the paint you may slap on your face to impress the new boss is your business. But what about your daily bread?</p>
        </article>
```

[Link to Codepen](https://codepen.io/semblance/pen/XexVbB)

Comment: You need to handle CSS for each article you add to the CSS grid system.

Comment: @AmilaSenadheera could you give me a codepen demo or something please by adding some posts

Answer (score 1):

you need to change class name and also add css for that class

i have added below class for new item

```
featured-image-5, number-5, article-5
```

```css
*, *:before, *:after { 
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  background: #eee;
  color: #191919;
  font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
}

h1, h2 {
  font-family: 'Fjalla One', sans-serif;
  margin-top: 0;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

figure {
  margin: 0;
}

img {
  height: auto;
  width: 100%;  
}

.wrapper {
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 20px;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 2fr;
  grid-auto-rows: minmax(100px, auto);
  margin: 24px;
  max-width: 1000px;
  position: relative;
}

.wrapper > * {
  grid-column: 1 / span 2;
}

.header {
  font-size: 1.5em;
  grid-row: 1 / 2;
}

header:after {
  background: #6817ba;
  content: "";
  display: block;
  height: 20px;
  width: auto;
}

.article {
  text-align: right;
}

.featured-image-1 {
  grid-row: 2 / 3;
}

.number-1 {
  grid-row: 2 / 4;
}

.featured-image-2, .number-2 {
  grid-row: 4 / 5;
}

.number-1, .number-4 {
  align-self: end;
  color: rgba(104,23,186,0.5);
  font-family: 'Fjalla One', sans-serif;
  font-size: 480px;
  line-height: 480px;
  grid-column: 1 / 2;
}

.article-1, .article-4 {
  grid-column: 2 / 3;
}

.featured-image-2, .number-2 {
  align-self: end;
}

.number-2 {
  color: #eee;
  font-size: 200px;
  justify-self: end;
  line-height: 160px;
}

.number-3, .number-5 {
  background: black;
  border-radius: 130px;
  color: white;
  font-family: 'Fjalla One', sans-serif;
  font-size: 100px;
  height: 130px;
  line-height: 130px;
  position: absolute;
  grid-row: 6 / 7;
  right: -20px;
  text-align: center;
  top: -20px;
  width: 130px;
}

.featured-image-3 img {
  height: 100%;
}

.number-4 {
  font-size: 320px;
  left: -20px;
  line-height: 320px;
  position: absolute;
}

@media (min-width: 600px) {
  
  .wrapper {
    grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr 2fr);
    margin: 24px auto;
  }
  
  .header {
    grid-column: 3 / 5;
    width: 70%;
  }
  
  .featured-image-1 {
    grid-row: 1 / 3;
  }
  
  .article-1 {
    grid-row: 3 / 4;
  }
  
  .article-2 {
    grid-column: 4 / 5;
    grid-row: 4 / 5;
  }
  
  .featured-image-2, .number-2 {
    grid-column: 3 / 5;
    grid-row: 2 / 4;
  }

  .featured-image-3, .number-3 {
    grid-row: 4 / 6;
  }
  
  .featured-image-4, .number-4 {
    grid-column: 3 / 5;
    grid-row: 5 / 6;
  }
    
  .featured-image-5, .number-5 {
    grid-row: 7 / 8;
  }
  
  .number-4 {
    font-size: 320px;
    grid-row: 5 / 7;
  }
  
  .article-3, .article-4 {
    grid-row: 6 / 7;
  }
  
  .article-4 {
    grid-column: 4 / 5;
  }

  
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <header class="header"><h1>Innovators of the new genre</h1></header>
  <figure class="featured-image-1">
      <img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/579121/karina-carvalho-87594-sm.jpg" alt="Photo by Karina Carvalho on Unsplash">
   </figure>
  <div class="number-1">1</div>
  <article class="article article-1">
    <h2>Technical information</h2>
    <p>In 1985 Aldus Corporation launched its first desktop publishing program Aldus PageMaker for Apple Macintosh computers.</p>
  </article>
  <figure class="featured-image-2">
      <img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/579121/jc-dela-cuesta-311203-sm.jpg" alt="Photo by JC Dela Cuesta on Unsplash">
   </figure>
  <div class="number-2">2</div>
  <article class="article article-2">
    <h2>Variants</h2>
    <p>Released in 1987 for PCs running Windows 1.0.</p>
  </article>
  <figure class="featured-image-3">
      <img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/579121/seth-doyle-151915-sm.jpg" alt="Photo by Seth Doyle on Unsplash">
   </figure>
  <div class="number-3">3</div>
  <article class="article article-3">
    <h2>When not to use it</h2>
    <p>The toppings you may chose for that TV dinner pizza slice when you forgot to shop for foods, the paint you may slap on your face to impress the new boss is your business. But what about your daily bread?</p>
  </article>
  <figure class="featured-image-4">
      <img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/579121/tim-marshall-189232-sm.jpg" alt="Photo by Tim Marshall on Unsplash">
   </figure>
  <div class="number-4">4</div>
  <article class="article article-4">
    <h2>So Lorem Ipsum is bad</h2>
    <p>One of the villagers, Kristina Halvorson from Adaptive Path, holds steadfastly to the notion that design can’t be tested without real content.</p>
  </article>
  <figure class="featured-image-5 ">
        <img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/579121/seth-doyle-151915-sm.jpg" alt="Photo by Seth Doyle on Unsplash">
    </figure>
    <div class="number-5">5</div>
    <article class="article article-5">
        <h2>Introduction of the Study</h2>
        <p>The toppings you may chose for that TV dinner pizza slice when you forgot to shop for foods, the paint you may slap on your face to impress the new boss is your business. But what about your daily bread?</p>
    </article>
</div>
```

Comment: Could you give me an added demo with some more blog posts. i mean adding 6 7 and 8th blog post like 1st and second some more classess.. Thanks

Comment: i mean repeating the 4th number in 6th position. Could you please make another post!!

Comment: please help me on this..